# Why am I getting a read-only error when trying to use lightning:recordForm to create an Account?

Tags: javascript, lightning-record-form

Any ideas why I'm getting the following error when trying to execute the code below?:

> Action failed:
>   c:CreateAccount$controller$handleAccountFormLoad
>   ["Phone" is read-only] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:CreateAccount$controller$handleAccountFormLoad}

**CreateAccount.cmp**

```
<lightning:recordForm
        objectApiName="Account"
        columns="2"
        layoutType="Full"
        mode="view"
        aura:id="accountForm"
        recordTypeId="{!v.personRecordTypeId}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleAccountFormSuccess}"
        onload="{!c.handleAccountFormLoad}"
        oncancel="{!c.handleAccountFormCancel}"
/>
```

**CreateAccountController.js**

```
handleAccountFormLoad: function(component, event, helper){
    helper.handleAccountFormLoad(component, event);
}
```

**CreateAccountHelper.js**

```
handleAccountFormLoad: function(component, event){
    if(component.get('v.autoCreateAccount')){

        let record = event.getParam('record');
        let fields = record['fields'];
        let accountForm = component.find('accountForm');
        let content = component.get('v.resultContent');

        fields.Phone = content.phoneFormatted;
        fields.FirstName = content.firstname;
        fields.LastName = content.lastname;
        fields.PersonEmail = content.email;

        accountForm.submit(fields);
    }
},
```

Comment: you're moving the goal posts here. you should ask a different question next time you get an answer and a new field is throwing an issue. I do suggest you also look into what you're doing here on your form.

Comment: The answer you gave, Ronnie, is not accurate. I'm not trying to directly write to the Account Name field. Salesforce allows writing to Account.FirstName and Account.LastName on a person account.

Comment: exactly in my post i described that this needs to be done on the contact for that account.

Comment: That isn't correct/relevant/necessary. I am able to successfully insert person accounts via other means by populating the Account.FirstName and Account.LastName fields, which propagate to the person contact.


The issue I'm surfacing here is that the JavaScript object to which I'm trying to write is read-only.

Comment: So create a copy and update the copy?

Comment: Thank you, Ronnie, for the suggestion to create a copy and update it. Object.assign fixed the problem.

Comment: I'll update my answer so it can help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The issue is that a person account cannot be written to on that field.This field is autopopulated based on the related contact:</s>

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm

What you will have to do instead is populate the `PersonContactId` field with the `Id` of the contact for whom you want to create the person account for. This will associate the Name field based on that contact. Setting values after the form has loaded is not ideal, you should instead preload them to a variable, use a `recordEditForm` and assign the value to your `lightningInputField`'s `value` attribute. Since it appears that you are just auto submitting the form, move to an `onsubmit` to set these values instead and you should be able to set any writeable fields there. and then you will be able to submit by calling `submit(field)` to submit your changed fields.

Also on a side note, your form is `mode="view"` which places all fields as read-only

**Edit:**

You can use Object reassignment to make an editable copy of your record. Simple example for others that visit this post would look like this:

`const copy = { ...record };`

after you have made a copy, all elements within the copy can be updated as you need.

Comment: I get the read-only error regardless of which field I try to write to first. I've now updated the message and code above to reflect that.

Comment: but the `onload` of a form is all read only, i do have another solution.  you should do any changes in the `onsubmit`, I have updated my response accordingly. Try in the future when one part of a question is answered to NOT update to change the question, but ask a new question. It helps no one when you downvote a correct answer only to change the criteria in your question after the change was implemented.

Comment: mode="view" does not place all fields as read-only. mode="readonly" does that.

Comment: let consumer = Object.assign({}, fields);